# Why does Heat travel from a higher average KE measure to a lower average KE measure?

Tags: thermodynamics

Heat is the total energy of the motion of the molecules of a substance, whereas temperature refers to the measure of the average energy of the motions of the molecules in the substance.

So when a spark falls into boiling water the temperature of the spark is greater but it has lower total heat energy but a higher average KE compared to boiling water, so shouldn't heat travel from a higher total KE measure to a lower total KE measure i.e. from water to spark, and not from a higher average KE measure to a lower average KE measure i.e. from spark to water.

But it doesn't, why?

Answer (score 1):

> Heat is the total energy of the motion of the molecules of a substance

Heat is not the total energy of the motion. Heat is the transfer of energy due solely to temperature difference. The energy of motion is properly called the kinetic energy component of the internal energy of a substance.

> whereas temperature refers to the measure of the average energy of the
> motions of the molecules in the substance.

Roughly, yes.

> so shouldn't heat travel from a higher total KE measure to a lower
> total KE measure i.e. from water to spark,

It is not the total KE of the spark and the total KE of the water that determines the direction of heat transfer. It is the temperature of the spark and the temperature of the water that determines the direction of heat transfer (in this case from the higher temperature spark to lower temperature water). The temperature is a measure of the average KE, not the total KE.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Heat is not the total energy of motion of molecules. It is a mode of energy transfer in which energy transfer occurs from the body at a higher temperature to a body at a lower temperature.

Temperature can be crudely defined as the average kinetic energy of the atoms or molecules of the system. According to the second law of thermodynamics, heat transfer occurs from the body at a higher temperature to a body at a lower temperature.

To clarify your doubt, you can have a million litres of water in one container at $300 K$ and a few mililitres of water at $350 K$ in another container. If these two containers were brought in contact, heat transfer would occur from the small container to the large one, even though the larger one has *more molecular motion*.